unable to fill an array with numbers from input in java
I'm trying to set an array with desired length of numbers.
It has to get the numbers from user but it throws an exception error after getting the first one.
Can anyone help me to fix this please?
import java.util.Scanner;

public class t4NumericalOperations {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    double[] numbers = new double[n];

    public void readNumbers(){
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to do caculations on? ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your numbers : ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}

class testSum{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t4NumericalOperations col1 = new t4NumericalOperations();
        col1.readNumbers();
        col1.calculate();
        col1.display();
    }
}

The output is like this:
How many numbers do you want to do caculations on? 
2
Enter your numbers : 
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at exercises1.ch4.t4NumericalOperations.readNumbers(t4NumericalOperations.java:15)
        at exercises1.ch4.testSum.main(t4NumericalOperations.java:36)
 


double[] numbers = new double[n]; what's the value of n at the point of this declaration? Hint: it can't possibly be the one you read from the user because the array has already been instantiated when you read the user input.

Your array is created before you read n.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266034/why-am-i-getting-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0

But if I create the array after reading n how can I use this array in other methods of this class?

That's a good link, but only shows local array variables.  I guess for students the leap from local to instance variable is a little large.  @BackSlash

You must declare the variable as an instance variable, but allocate the array after the number is read.
public class T4NumericalOperations {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    double[] numbers;   // declaration only

    public void readNumbers(){
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to do caculations on? ");
        n = input.nextInt();
        numbers = new double[n];  // allocate the array here
        System.out.println("Enter your numbers : ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}

Note: I have changed the name of the class from t4NumericalOperations  to T4NumericalOperations. I highly recommend you follow the Java naming convention.

As per your code, you are trying to dynamically populate the number of elements for an Double array. you can try this method instead.
double[] numbers ;
public void readNumbers(){
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to do caculations on? ");
    n = input.nextInt();
    numbers = new double[n];
    System.out.println("Enter your numbers : ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

You are instantiating the numbers variable outside the method which is dynamically adding array size which is not a valid. Java will initialise variable n as 0. that's why you are getting ArrayOutOfBound Exception.
